# Remove leading or trailing whitespace of string except html tag in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove leading or trailing whitespace of string except html tag

example

```
html = <a class=\"c-grid__quotation--link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.yahoo.com/\"><div class=\"c-grid__quotation text--s-md p-topic__quotation__border c-border-r-5\">\n  <div class=\"c-flex\">\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--main\">\n      <img src=\"https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130909/y_200_a.png\" alt=\"Y 200 a\" />\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side\">\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-title text--b\">\n        Yahoo\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-description\">\n        News, email and search are just the beginning. Discover more every day. Find your yodel.\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-url\">\n        www.yahoo.com\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div></a>
```

My way of Doing this

```
html.gsub(/>\s{1,8}</, "><").gsub(/>\s{1,8}/, ">").gsub(/\s{1,8}</, "<")
```

How to remove blanks depends on the pattern.

Is there any better way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [positive lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
html = %| <a class=\"c-.......| # your line goes here
html.gsub(/(?<=>)\s+|\s+(?=<)/, '')
```

The above means “remove all whitespace after `'>'` or before `'<'`.”

Comment: I knew posite lookarounds for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Try Following:

```
html = "<a class=\"c-grid__quotation--link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.yahoo.com/\"><div class=\"c-grid__quotation text--s-md p-topic__quotation__border c-border-r-5\">\n  <div class=\"c-flex\">\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--main\">\n      <img src=\"https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130909/y_200_a.png\" alt=\"Y 200 a\" />\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side\">\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-title text--b\">\n        Yahoo\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-description\">\n        News, email and search are just the beginning. Discover more every day. Find your yodel.\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-url\">\n        www.yahoo.com\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div></a>"
```

-> `html.squeeze(' ').strip`

**output:**

```
"<a class=\"c-grid__quotation--link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.yahoo.com/\"><div class=\"c-grid__quotation text--s-md p-topic__quotation__border c-border-r-5\"> <div class=\"c-flex\"> <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--main\"> <img src=\"https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130909/y_200_a.png\" alt=\"Y 200 a\" /> </div> <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side\"> <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-title text--b\"> Yahoo </div> <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-description\"> News, email and search are just the beginning. Discover more every day. Find your yodel. </div> <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-url\"> www.yahoo.com </div> </div> </div> </div></a>"
```

Comment: Oh, the method I first learned.
There are also methods like this.
Thank you!

Comment: Neither `squish` nor `squeeze` does not implement the requested functionality. This answer is simply incorrect.